# https api response is getting cached with apache httpclient

Tags: java, caching, cron, httpclient

I am using Apache HTTPClient to make remote API call. This process runs via a cron.
API responses are getting cached due to some reason. When i make same API call from rest client, it shows latest data. But, when process (woken up by cron) makes this call, it is getting cached response (not the latest data).

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 2):

There is no caching within httpclient. Since you always run a new Java VM via cron everything is fresh, anyways.

Please check that you don't use any intermediate proxy with httpclient that may cause problems. A proxy could be configured via -Dhttp.proxyHost=... and -Dhttp.proxyPort=....

Second, you simply might get another result because of the request you sent is different. Not the URL itself may differ, but the headers!

Try setting headers that may trigger a different behavior, e.g.:

```
HttpGet g = ....
g.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
g.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
g.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"); // mimics a browser REST request
```

Also try to enable the *org.apache.http.headers* logging target and compare the headers send by your REST client and the apache http client library.